# /etc/hosts, localhost and docker port forwarding question

Tags: docker, networking, dns

I have a docker container running that forwards all host connections to port 8545 to its internal 8545 port:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                     COMMAND                  CREATED        STATUS        PORTS                                                                                            NAMES
ae9aee5c7fbc   ops-bedrock-l1            "/bin/sh /entrypoint…"   45 hours ago   Up 45 hours   0.0.0.0:8545-8546->8545-8546/tcp, 30303/tcp, 30303/udp, 0.0.0.0:7060->6060/tcp                   ops-bedrock-l1-1
```

I start a process on the host (not docker container) that listens on `127.0.0.1:8545`.

My `/etc/hosts` file looks like

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1 localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1 localhost
```

Now calls to http://localhost:8545 are forwarded to the docker-container process, whereas calls to http://127.0.0.1:8545 are forwarded to the host process. Can someone explain this behavior?

Is "localhost" somehow being redirected to the ipv6 ::1 and that gets sent to the docker container process? Or is there something else going on?